# Find the vertices on the outline of a 3d model

Tags: opengl, ogre, outline

I have found a lot of materials on how to **draw** outline around a model with the help of a stencil buffer, like https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/code/samples/mjktips/StenciledHaloEffect.html

However, this time I need to locate the vertices on the outline, to get their coordinates, but haven't found an elegant way to do so.

I once came across a method that can solve my problem for simple models like cube or sphere. It suggests to check the two triangles that share an edge, if the normals of the two triangles pointing in opposite directions with respect to the camera direction, than the edge they share is on the outline.

The above method works for simple models like sphere or cube, but not for complex models because it might also picked up those edges that inside the outline from the view of the camera.

In conclusion, my objective is to find the coordinates of the vertices on the outline, for example, vertices on the red line in the image which you can find at https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/59361/opengl-get-the-outline-of-multiple-overlapping-objects.

BTW, I am doing this using Ogre.

Comment: I have been struggling with the same problem. At the very least you'll have to assume your model is watertight to avoid most of the complexity, but even then as far as I know there's no reliable general method available. I have asked a professor in computer graphics about this, and he didn't have a good answer either. Perhaps the best way is to make a secondary model that contains nothing inside, then do backface culling on all vertices.